# rosrun vs roslaunch

Tags: navigation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a continuation from [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/32199/why-amcl-is-not-working?answer=32248#post-id-32248) problem.

[Eric Perko](http://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) asked me to change odom_frame_id to odom_combined. (I need to change base_frame_id to base_footprint as well)

### *1st case rosrun:*

I have managed to do it using rosrun

```
rosrun amcl amcl _base_frame_id:=base_footprint _odom_frame_id:=odom_combined
```

and it works base_frame_id is changed to base_footprint and odom_frame_id is changed to odom_combined.

however

### *2nd case roslaunch:*

I tried using particularly these two lines (the complete code is shown at the bottom of this post amcl_diff_with_map_hwk.launch):

```
<param name="base_frame_id" value="base_footprint"/>
  <param name="odom_frame_id" value="odom_combined"/>
```

The base_frame_id is changed to base_footprint however odom_frame_id is still the default value which is odom. (As shown in the rosparam get /amcl below)

[image description http://i1214.photobucket.com/albums/cc484/torresho/rosparam_amcl_error.png](http://i1214.photobucket.com/albums/cc484/torresho/rosparam_amcl_error.png)

---

***************Why the odom_frame_id stays the same in the launch file case?*******************

---

amcl_diff_with_map_hwk.launch:

```
<launch>

<node pkg="amcl" type="amcl" name="amcl" output="screen">
  <!--param name="use_map_topic " value="true"/ -->
  <!-- Publish scans from best pose at a max of 10 Hz -->
  <param name="odom_model_type" value="diff"/>
  <param name="odom_alpha5" value="0.1"/>
  <param name="base_frame_id" value="base_footprint"/>
  <param name="odom_frame_id" value="odom_combined"/>

  <param name="transform_tolerance" value="0.2" />
  <param name="gui_publish_rate" value="10.0"/>
  <param name="laser_max_beams" value="30"/>
  <param name="min_particles" value="500"/>
  <param name="max_particles" value="5000"/>
  <param name="kld_err" value="0.05"/>
  <param name="kld_z" value="0.99"/>
  <param name="odom_alpha1" value="0.2"/>
  <param name="odom_alpha2" value="0.2"/>
  <!-- translation std dev, m -->
  <param name="odom_alpha3" value="0.8"/>
  <param name="odom_alpha4" value="0.2"/>
  <param name="laser_z_hit" value="0.5"/>
  <param name="laser_z_short" value="0.05"/>
  <param name="laser_z_max" value="0.05"/>
  <param name="laser_z_rand" value="0.5"/>
  <param name="laser_sigma_hit" value="0.2"/>
  <param name="laser_lambda_short" value="0.1"/>
  <param name="laser_model_type" value="likelihood_field"/>
  <!-- <param name="laser_model_type" value="beam"/> -->
  <param name="laser_likelihood_max_dist" value="2.0"/>
  <param name="update_min_d" value="0.2"/>
  <param name="update_min_a" value="0.5"/>
  <param name="odom_frame_id" value="odom"/>
  <param name="resample_interval" value="1"/>
  <param name="transform_tolerance" value="0.1"/>
  <param name="recovery_alpha_slow" value="0.0"/>
  <param name="recovery_alpha_fast" value="0.0"/>
  
</node>
</launch>
```

move_base.launch:

```
<launch>
  <master auto="start"/>

  <!-- Run the map server -->
  <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(find not_good)/Maps/Slam/slam_map_dark2.pgm 0.05"/>
 
  <!-- tf /map to /odom_combined -->
  <!-- node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="map_to_odom_combined" args="100 100 0 0 0 0 /map /odom_combined 100"/ -->

  <!--- Run AMCL -->
  <include file="$(find not_good)/amcl_diff_with_map_hwk.launch" />

  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <rosparam file="$(find not_good)/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find not_good)/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find not_good)/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find not_good)/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find not_good)/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

run it using
roslaunch move_base.launch

p.s. By the way the  `<param name="transform_tolerance" value="0.2" />` does not change the default value which is 0.1 as well.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33319/rosrun-vs-roslaunch/) by [Torres](https://answers.ros.org/users/2035/torres/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2012-05-04

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In your `amcl_diff_with_map_hwk.launch` file, you have `odom_frame_id` listed twice, once near the top with the value of `odom_combined` and once near the bottom with the value `odom`. When you have the same parameter listed multiple times, it retains the last value set, in this case, `odom`. Your `transform_tolerance` parameter has the same problem.

Remove the extra lines so that you are only setting the parameters once to the value you want and it should work.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Torres](https://answers.ros.org/users/2035/torres/) on 2012-05-10**:
I know it is absolutely a beginner's mistake. Thank you for being patient with me.

**Comment by [Torres](https://answers.ros.org/users/2035/torres/) on 2012-05-10**:
Thanks again =)